# getPermalink in gmail shows only first message

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-apps

I'm scripting on two different gmail accounts. On the first account, `getPermalink()` gives the full thread conversation, while on second it always shows only first message in thread.

```
thread.getPermalink()
```

I have checked gmail settings on both accounts but there aren't any significant differences.

Do you have the same issues with `getPermalink()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the Google Apps Script [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getPermalink()), the `getPermalink()` only works with the classic Gmail interface, not Inbox and it logs the permalink for the first thread in the inbox.

Here is the code for it.

```
// Logs the permalink for the first thread in the inbox
var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0];
Logger.log(thread.getPermalink());
```

Also, check if you have full permission to the gmail account

Comment: I use `GmailApp.search('in:inbox subject:[quest] after:' + lastDate);`
Also I have full permision and Gmail is in classic mode NOT Inbox